# Corona SDK - Create Health Bar with different HP value

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, game-physics

I have a rectangle image I use for a Health Bar fill. As your health goes down, the width of the bar decreases until you get to 0. For this part of the code everything works fine, the bar's width goes down and it stays in the same x position as its width is being changed.

My problem is when I create monster with different HP value, I will get different width of the Health Bar. How can I create the same size rectangle with different HP value?
Thank you so much.

```
 -- Create Health Bar 
MonsterBar = display.newRect( 20, 160, 26, 10 )
MonsterBar:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
MonsterBar:setFillColor( 80,150, 0 )

-- Monster get hit

MonsterBar.width = MonsterBar.width - scoreHUD.text
MonsterBar:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a percentile intermediate value, that you can then use in your progress bar.

For example, compute a monster health percent like that, making sure HP Current is <= HP Max:

```
local nMonsterHPPercentile = (nMonsterHPCurrent / nMonsterHPMax) * 100
```

Once you have the percentile value, adapt your rectangle to be created with a max size of "100" for example (or 200, 300 etc but you will need to multiply the monster percentile) and display the individual rectangles according to calculated percentile...
For example, if you got 62% for nMonsterHPPercentile, and the rectangle has width 100, do a loop that adds an individual hp rectangle to the bar for each 10%.